# Variables in "systemd" file?

Tags: linux, systemd

I have this systemd file:

```
  [Unit]
  Description=something website
  After=syslog.target
  Requires=postgresql.service

  [Service]
  ExecStart=/home/my_user/my_webapp/bin/ foreground
  ExecStop=/home/my_user/my_webapp/bin/ stop
  Restart=on-abort
  WorkingDirectory=/home/my_user/my_webapp/bin
  SyslogIdentifier=my_webapp_web_app
  User=my_user

  [Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

As you can see, "my_webapp" and "my_user" are repeated many times. Is there any way to store them into variables and use the variables instead?

Comment: Have you read the man page or tried anything?

Answer (score 3):

Probably the closest thing that would match your needs is using the `EnvironmentFile` option.

```
# file: /home/my_user/my_webapp/environment
# included in systemd unit my_webapp
# EnvironmentFile=-/home/my_user/my_webapp/environment
BASEDIR=/home/my_user/my_webapp
```

And your new unit

```
[Unit]
Description=something website
After=syslog.target
Requires=postgresql.service

[Service]
ExecStart=$BASEDIR/bin/ foreground
ExecStop=$BASEDIR/bin/ stop
Restart=on-abort
WorkingDirectory=$BASEDIR/bin
SyslogIdentifier=my_webapp_web_app
User=my_user

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You would probably want your variables set differently.  I'll leave that up to you to adjust.